# jQuery dataTables are not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, datatables

These are the style sheets i used

```js
<link href="<?php echo  Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/css/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

And

```js
<script src="<?php echo  Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/js/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo  Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl; ?>/js/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My Scripts are

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        alert("test");
            $("#example1").dataTable();
            $('#example2').dataTable({
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": true,
                "bInfo": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My tables are

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
</table>
```

In my page the search option and pagination are not working...

Please help me..
Try to fix this...
Thanks..

Comment: How are you populating the datatables?

Comment: Looks a little bit strange. Initializing a dataTable without <thead> and <tbody>, without specifying some kind of datasource, will produce errors in the console and the dataTable will never get initialised.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i would recommend you to search if someone else already created some extension for this plugin and use it: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/edatatables/ it looks great!

if you dont want to use extension and want to use your own code, try using the browser developer tools to view if there is any javascript errors, if no make sure the javascript and css are loaded, if none of these helps, try pasting here the full code of the table so we will see if there is any problems with the data maybe, i dont see something wrong with the code you pasted just make sure its version 1.9 and not 1.10, in 1.10 the options are little bit different, you can see it here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/